# Custom ordering using Analytical Functions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Display the list of employees from emp and ordered by deptno where null deptno should appear first, then courses with deptno=2 should appear and rest in ascending order.

i tried following query with DECODE,

```
SELECT   empno, ename, deptno
    FROM emp
ORDER BY DECODE (deptno, NULL, 0, 2, 1, 3);
```

but, i'm unable to achieve it through analytical functions.

Someone please help me solve this using analytical functions!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to assign `row_number()` based on the ordering, because the analytic functions do not "order" tables.  Did you try this?

```
SELECT empno, ename, deptno,
       row_number() over (ORDER BY DECODE (deptno, NULL, 0, 2, 1, 3) as seqnum
FROM emp ;
```

You could also do this without analytic functions at all:

```
select e.*, rownum as seqnum
from (SELECT empno, ename, deptno
      FROM emp
      ORDER BY DECODE (deptno, NULL, 0, 2, 1, 3)
     ) e
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records, replacing DECODE with a CASE (easier to read for me).
And imho to get the "rest in ascending order" you need to add deptno to the ELSE:

```
SELECT empno, ename, deptno,
   row_number() 
   over (ORDER BY case when deptno is NULL then -1
                       when deptno = 2 then 0
                       else deptno
                  end) as seqnum
FROM emp ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Even RANK() or DENSE_RANK() can be used as an analytical funciton,
ORDER BY clause should contain another venue_id to sort the else option of the DECODE.

SELECT   course_id, course_title, venue_id
    FROM ha_courses
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY DECODE (venue_id, NULL, 0, 2, 1, 3)),
         venue_id;